# html link, href assignment from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, href

I have a simple Javascript function which builds a Url that I want to provide a link to.

However, I can't seem to get the anchor tag working with it.  How do I assign the href of the anchor tag the results of the Javascript function?

Neither one of these work correctly:

```
<a href="getUrl();">Click here</a>
<a href="javascript:getUrl();">Click here</a>
```

This is what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUrl()
    {
        return "http://www.google.com";
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:document.location.href=getUrl();">Click here</a>
```

-- update --

If I wanted to incorporate user278064s' comments, i would change the above into:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function getUrl()
        {
            return "http://www.google.com";
        }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onClick="document.location.href=getUrl();">Click here</a>
```

Comment: is one of these considered to be better practice?

Comment: @miss.serena: Neither would win a beauty contest, but the 2nd one would be considered better back in the days. Because it keeps your statusbar more clean, without resorting to `onMouseOver`/`onMouseOut` code which rewrites the status bar.
But who uses the status bar anyway these days? ;)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me. A good way would be to create a new link in the function.

```js
function fetchURL() {
  var title = "Download";
  var URL = title.link("https://www.google.com");
  document.getElementById("dynamicButton").innerHTML = URL;

}
```

```html
<body onload="fetchURL()">
  <div id="dynamicButton">
    //empty
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="getUrl();" href="#">Click here</a>
```

[**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/ZZw3z/)

Comment: This does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Give the link an `id`:

```
<a id="specialLink">Click Here</a>
```

Later on, set its `href` from JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('specialLink').href = getUrl();
```

(You might want to include a placeholder `href` in the link which people with JavaScript disabled will see.)

Comment: What does 'later on' mean?  When the page loads, I want this link's href to point to the correct location so that when the link is clicked it takes the user to where I want them to go.  There really is no 'later on'.

Comment: @Mike “later on” just means “in any JavaScript which runs after the link on the page”. It could be a JavaScript file included at the end of the document, a function that runs when the page is ready, or a `<script>` block that you put just below the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrl(that) {
   return "www.whateveryouwant.com";
}

// Point the a.href attribute at your url.
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
a.href = getUrl();
```

**UPDATE**

I assume that you want to use the `getUrl()` method to set the href attribute, because probably the pointed url is not static (so it could change at any moment e point to the getUrl() returned url.)

Anyway, you could assign the href attribute, when i.e. the user click on the link, in this way.

```
function changeHref(aElem) {
   aElem.href = getUrl();
}
```

Following the complete code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeHref(this);">click me!</a>

<script>
   function getUrl(that) {
      return "www.whateveryouwant.com";
   }

   function changeHref(aElem) {
      aElem.href = getUrl();
   }
</script>
```

One other thing. You should avoid the use of `javascript: pseudo-protocol`.

This fragment will explain you why:

> A pseudo-protocol is a nonstandard take on this idea. 
>   The javascript: pseudo-protocol is supposed to be used to invoke JavaScript from within a link.
>   Here’s how the javascript: pseudo-protocol would be used to call the popUp function:

```
<a href="javascript:popUp('http://www.example.com/');">Example</a>
```

> This will work just fine in browsers that understand the javascript: pseudo-protocol. Older browsers, however, will attempt to follow the link and fail. Even in browsers that understand the pseudoprotocol,
>   the link becomes useless if JavaScript has been disabled.
>   In short, using the javascript: pseudo-protocol is usually a very bad way of referencing JavaScript
>   from within your markup.

**DOM Scripting: Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model: Second Edition**

Comment: I don't understand where the function should be called from.  When the page loads, I want the link to contain the proper address in the href.  Where does the code which you have outside of the function definition go?  How does the <a href=???> get assigned?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        document.getElementById("aTag").href = getUrl();
   });
</script>

<a id="aTag">Click Here</a>
```